# stream two event messages in one from gRPC Server

Tags: server, client, streaming, grpc, proto

I have a scenario where I am trying to send multiple messages in one and trying to stream the one message from the gRPC server to the gRPC client side.

My `proto` files on server side look like this:

```
Service Greeter{
rpc AccumulateEvents (EventRequest) returns (stream EventsMessage);
}
message EventsMessage{
    FirstEvent firstEvents =1;
    SecondEvents secondEvent = 2;
}

message EventRequest{
//sending empty request
}
```

The service method is as follows:

```
public override async Task AccumulateEvents(EventRequest eventRequest, IServerStreamWriter < EventsMessage > responseStream, ServerCallContext context) {
  IDisposable disposable4 = service.SubscribeToEvents(OnEvents);
  service.execute();
  await responseStream.WriteAsync(new EventsMessage {
    FirstEvent = firstEvent, SecondEvents = secondEvents
  });

}
```

When I am trying to fetch  and parse the stream from the client side,i am getting `null` for `secondEvent` part of the message `EventsMessage`. Only `firstEvents` was returned from the server to the client. I tried debugging and could see `secondEvent` getting populated but then it became null when the streaming started from the server.
Also, `secondEvent` is a repeated field. I am not sure if that is the reason of it becoming `null`.

Please let me know what i might be missing here.

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet on the client side, showing how these messages are received?

Comment: Also, can you please log the full EventsMessage in the server side code snippet, to make sure that secondEvents is populated?